# Chametz that is stuck to tape/velcro

Tags: chametz-leaven, bedikas-chametz, biur-chametz

What is one supposed to do with chametz that is stuck to something sticky like tape or velcro, that is impossible to remove completely but can be found and seen easily, in the lead up to pesach?

For example, if one has strong velcro holding together furniture etc. and there is chametz stuck in the fibres, or a corner of it is peeling off where it is stuck to the wall, and that  sticky side has got muck and dust on it, including crumbs of chametz.

Comment: I believe common practise is to spray them with some cleaning spray/bleach to render them inedible

Comment: @Dov thank you. If you write that as an answer I am happy to accept it.

Comment: i just need to find the source.

Comment: Why is there chametz on tape? Sounds like bittul is all you need since it's tiny and gross (unless I'm misunderstanding something)

Comment: @DoubleAA edited ty

Comment: Unless you're talking about a whole Cheerio stuck there that a kid would grab and eat, this kind of debris is exactly what bittul is for.

Comment: @DoubleAA awesome, I admire your knack for applying the halacha to practice and would hope you can find the time to write it up as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DoubleAA asserts if the crumbs are small, the bittul would suffice.

That aside, there is also the concept of “Yisrael Kedoshim Heim”, in other words since Jews are a holy people, there are those who take on to be extra stringent and try and eliminate even the smallest amount of chametz (e.g. see the [Tur 442](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.442.1?lang=bi), [Kaf HaChaim 442:69](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.442.69.1?lang=bi&p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.442.6&lang2=bi) etc.) (- Speak to your local Rov for guidance as to whether to apply these chumros or not.)

In such a scenario, a widespread practise is to spray cleaning fluid/bleach on the offending chametz, thereby rendering them inedible and therefore no longer an issue. It is the same principle as biur chametz, in that when the food becomes significantly spoiled it is no longer regarded as "food".

Note the [following](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/cleaning-for-pesach-where-does-one-have-to-clean-and-check-for-chametz-full-chapter/#_ftn67) based on the writings of the [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4284864/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-442-The-Laws-Applying-to-the-Obliteration-of-Food-Containing-a-Mixture-of-Chametz-Before-Pesach.htm#v30):

> Chametz that is stuck in a deep hole or crevice and cannot be reached with one’s hands, is not required to be removed and it suffices for him to nullify the Chametz before Pesach. This applies even if there is a Kezayis of visible Chametz found in the crevice. Nonetheless, practically, the Jewish people are holy and destroy all Chametz that is in one’s possession, even if the Chametz found in unreachable areas. Thus, when possible, one is to pour bleach or other spoiling agent over Chametz that he is unable to reach with his hands.

Comment: I have accepted. Following MY guidelines though, I should have waited a couple of days. If someone has any other answer, please feel free to post it.

Comment: No worries - we're all here to learn!

Comment: @Dov, The Question was more about chometz which are like crumbs which unless we are worried they are going to stick to each other to become one big edible thing. unless it is a gluska yofe according to the Gemora is Botul by itself. I do not remember anything disagreeing with this.
Once that is established and there is bitul, is there a reason to spray things on it?